# What are the performance of every selector's types?

Tags: puppeteer, e2e-testing, codeceptjs

In CodeceptJs, you have different way to select elements and manipulate them for e2e testing :

- CSS selector
- Xpath selector
- Semantic locator
- Locator builder

But I have some questions about their performance. Which are the best locator type ?
What is the ratio between them ?
Currently, I use Locator builder but I don't know if they're efficient like CSS selector or ID selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no performance metrics between type of locators for CodeceptJS, AFAIK.

**About locator types**

Locator builder just creates xpath locator.

CSS and xpath locator's has similar logic for helpers (WebDriver, Puppeteer, Playwright, etc).
Difference in speed appears in browser Driver level.

[AFAIK](https://help.mabl.com/docs/when-to-use-css-selectors-vs-xpath-ids), IE11 with WebDriver works faster with xpath, but Chrome and Firefox with css.
For Nightmare, for Puppeteer and others it may differ.

For semantic locators - it depends on type of locator.
It tries to find element with one strategy, than with others.
So, technically, there are high probability, that semantic locators will be slower.

**CodeceptJS tip**

And I don't know how really do you need performance tricks, but I know one tip (works for current and older versions, for <= 2.5.0):

If you specify type of selector, like `I.click({ css: "button#some-selector" });`, it will be a bit faster, than use of none specified selector `I.click("button#some-selector")` due to implementation of semantic (fuzzy) locators.

For non described locator type, Codecept will try to "guess" what type of locator do you use, and, in some cases, it will run same as semantic locator - with search a couple of times with different strategies.

**UPD** added info about locator types

Comment: I want to know that for my manager that ask me selectors' performances.
In Protractor, some kind of selector are slower than other : https://www.logigear.com/blog/test-automation/15-best-practices-for-building-an-awesome-protractor-framework/#section9

My question is about locate builder on Codecept. It seems to be powerful but what about the performance than css selector ?

Comment: Locator builder in codeceptjs creates xpath locators.

Difference in xpath/css locators depends on helper you use. I mean, you need to search performance difference between css/xpath for Puppeteer or WebDriverIO or Protractor.

Comment: Currently, I use Codecept with Puppeteer helper. I also use locator builders, I think there're no difference of speed.
Thank's for your help !